# Chrome's alert or confirm box action

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to capture Chrome's default alert box' or confirm box' clicks (OK or cancel, doesn't matter). Is there any way to do this? Unfortunately the console says nothing about the action, so I'm really clueless how to start...
Thanks!

Comment: thanks Quentin, unneeded tags removed.

Comment: I will assume that instead of "Chrome's default alert box' or confirm box'" you want to say "Browser default alert box or confirm box", because there is not an special box for Chrome's. It exist a default box for each browser.

Comment: good assumption. still, I need it for Chrome. thanks

Answer (score 1):

`alert()` will simply block until it is dismissed. It doesn't let the user make a choice.

`confirm()` will also block until it is dismissed. You can tell which option was picked by using its return value.

Comment: this does not answer my question.

Comment: @Riwi — If it doesn't, then your question is unclear. You might want to be more detailed about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: "I'm trying to capture Chrome's default alert box' or confirm box' clicks" - I really don't know how to make this more detailed

Comment: @Riwi — Quoting yourself is not going to change my understanding of what those words mean. Step back and explain what you hope to achieve by "capturing".

Comment: in this case I'm afraid it's your understanding that has to be changed rather than my question.

Comment: @Riwi — The only way to change my understanding is to change the question.

Comment: maybe a bit of explanation helps: I inject a script into a field which returns a pop up window: <script>alert("hi");</script>. now a pop up window pops up, right? I want to do some action as soon as the pop up window's OK button clicked. my question is therefore how could I identify this OK button click, as I have no id for this window by default. hope this helps.

Comment: Edit the script so your action appears immediately after `<script>alert("hi");</script>`

Comment: sorry, I don't get you. why sould I edit the script? the script does what it needs to do: pops up a window which says "hi". it is working fine, and out of the question.

Comment: @Riwi — Clearly it doesn't do what it needs to do, you want to do something else when the alert is dismissed.